# I have orders.something.com and hr.something.com. How can I login into both systems?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a site orders.something.com and other site hr.something.com. My 1st question should I create different applications for these in VS 2010 or I can run it inside single application too? Secondly, if I create 2 applications how can I establish login into both system? So for example if he is logged into something.com, he is authenticated into orders.something.com as well as hr.something.com?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: creating two separate application doesn't make sense to me. If you do need to create two separate applications for some reason, then we need more elaborative question from you including details. For using the same login, you can use cookies with authentication details and expiration time and use the same cookie in both the applications.

Comment: If I don't create 2 separate applications, how will I get url like orders.something.com and hr.something.com? Also if I create two applications, how will the cookie be sent to other application because I think cookie is limited to particular domain. In this case subdomains are going to be different.

Comment: @Jaggu, it's possible to associate a single web site with multiple host headers so you may have single application serving both sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, whether both should be different applications or not can be decided by the functionality - if both solve different concerns then you can have different applications.

Further, having different applications can give you isolation - you can scale both independently, both can have different down-times/upgrade frequency/maintenance plans. Both sites may need different SLA (service level agreements) and in such case, it does make sense to have them separate applications.

Even if they are separate applications, they can use SSO if authentication store is the same. For example, you may use integrated windows authentication. In case of ASp.NET forms authentication, you can set the [authentication cookie domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx) to the parent domain (`something.com`) and that would make the same token valid for both sub-domains.

Comment: thanks, I understood everything except can you give me links of how can I set multiple host headers and secondly where can I get examples of SSO in C#

Comment: Edit bindings for the web site (Each binding is a combination of IP address, port and host header). As explained, you get SSO if you use integrated windows authentication or forms authentication with cookie domain set to the parent domain. Are you trying use some other authentication scheme - if yes then SSO implementation will depend upon what scheme you are using.

Comment: I am using Forms authentication only. After creating host header do I have to configure DNS too?

Comment: Both host headers need to resolve to the server's IP address. Whether it needs DNS re-configuration or not depends upon your DNS setup.